# f: M $\rightarrow $ R is continuous if and only if for every a $\in$ R, $X_a$ and $Y_a$ are open sets

Tags: analysis, continuity

$f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $X_a$ = {x $\in$ M | f(x) < a} and $Y_a$ = {x $\in$ M | f(x) > a} are open sets.

( $\implies$) If f is continuous, then $f^{-1}$(A) is open for every A $\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then, $X_a$ = $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is open. Similarly, $Y_a$ is open.

Can anyone help me to prove that if $X_a$ and $Y_a$ are open for every a, then f is continuous?

Comment: Not "for every $A\subset \mathbb R$." But for some $A$, yes...

Answer (score 1):

($\Leftarrow$) For every bounded interval $f^{-1}[(a, b)] = X_b \cap Y_a$, so that's an intersection of open sets and therefore open. If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, then $U$ is a union of open intervals, and $f^{-1}$ distributes over the union, so $f^{-1}[U]$ a union of open sets of the form $f^{-1}[(a, b)]$ and is therefore open.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

You have to prove that the inverse image of every open subset of $\mathbb R$ is open. And an open subset of $\mathbb R$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals.

The inverse image of a union is the union of the inverse images. And the inverse image of an open interval is either a $X_a$, a $Y_a$ or an intersection $X_a \cap Y_b$.